# why fail2ban does not ban? (ubuntu, ssh)

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, iptables, fail2ban

I installed a fresh Ubuntu machine. Then I changed the ssh port which is no more 22 but 22111:

Then I have installed fail2ban:

```
apt-get install fail2ban -y
cp /etc/fail2ban/jail.conf /etc/fail2ban/jail.local
service fail2ban restart
iptables -L
```

Then I try to SSH login from the ip 192.168.1.22. After few wrong login, fail2ban add the follow line to iptables.

```
-A fail2ban-ssh -s 192.168.1.22/32 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
```

After that, I try to login again with the right credential and I can login with no problem, from the IP 192.168.1.22

The iptables rule is still there.

Do I need additional configuration?

Comment: We would need to see the complete iptables ruleset for the INPUT and related chains. My guess is that there is an earlier rule that allows this connection.

Comment: if you changed ssh port in sshd_config only but not in fail2ban config it bans your ip for port 22 but not 22111.

Comment: @Dodge The iptables rule given by the OP as added does not specify a port, so should apply to all ports (*and* protocols). Iain's hypothesis sounds more credible to me.

Comment: @Iain here is the iptable: `-P INPUT ACCEPT
-P FORWARD ACCEPT
-P OUTPUT ACCEPT
-N fail2ban-ssh
-A INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 22 -j fail2ban-ssh
-A fail2ban-ssh -j RETURN`

Comment: The fail2ban rules are in their own chain.  You need a rule to pass new connections through the chain before the rules accepting the connection. This would likely be the second or third rule.  It helps to check the counters in iptables to see which rules are being hit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already mentioned in the comment, you need to change the `port` value in `jail.local` file to your custom port number that the ssh is listening to.

```
[ssh]

enabled  = true
port     = 22111 # custom port here
filter   = sshd
logpath  = /var/log/auth.log
maxretry = 6
```

This is because, this port number is used to create the iptables rule for the INPUT chain, as below, from your post:

```
-N fail2ban-ssh -A INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 22 -j fail2ban-ssh
```

See the value of `--dports 22`, which means those packet will be matched first that are destined for port 22 and hence, when you are trying to log into another port, it is not matching and therefore the  flollowing rule for that specific ip is not getting employed:

```
-A fail2ban-ssh -s 192.168.1.22/32 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
```

Change the port and restart fail2ban, and then check iptables rules again, you will see, it is changed and then thing should work as expected.

Comment: In 'jail.local' changing the port from 22 to 22111 (my SSH port number) solved the problem. Thanks.

Comment: @David, You are welcome and glad that you could sort it out.